# Dynamic ExpandableListView from JSON

Tags: android, json, dynamic, expandablelistview

I want to fill an `ExpandableListView` from a JSON file which is parsed.

The goal is to put the first entry (kontakt_titel) as the title of the group and all the others as children...

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"contact":[
  {
     "kontakt_titel":"Berlin",
     "adresse_strasse":"Hauptstrasse 1",
     "adresse_plzort":"4000 Berlin",
     "telefon":"123456789",
     "fax":"123456780",
     "email":"berlin@123.com",
     "website":"www.berlin.123.com"
  },
  {
     "kontakt_titel":"London",
     "adresse_strasse":"East Highway 1",
     "adresse_plzort":"London",
     "telefon":"123456789",
     "fax":"123456780",
     "email":"london@123.com",
     "website":"www.london.123.com"
  },
  {
     "kontakt_titel":"New York",
     "adresse_strasse":"Time Square 1",
     "adresse_plzort":"12345",
     "telefon":"123456789",
     "fax":"123456780",
     "email":"newyork@123.com",
     "website":"www.newyork.123.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

And this is the code where I want to parse those elements into the ExpandableListView:

```
try {
        JSONArray jContact = json.getJSONArray("contact");
        for (int i = 0; i < jContact.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c4 = jContact.getJSONObject(i);

            String contact_title = c4.getString("kontakt_titel");
            String adresse_strasse = c4.getString("adresse_strasse");
            String adresse_plzort = c4.getString("adresse_plzort");
            String telefon = c4.getString("telefon");
            String fax = c4.getString("fax");
            String email = c4.getString("email");
            String website = c4.getString("website");

            if (contact_title != null && !contact_title.equals("")) {
                contactTitles.add(contact_title);
            } else {
                contactTitles.add("");
            }
            if (adresse_strasse != null && !adresse_strasse.equals("")) {
                contactAddressStreet.add(adresse_strasse);
            } else {
                contactAddressStreet.add("");
            }
            if (adresse_plzort != null && !adresse_plzort.equals("")) {
                contactAddressPlzOrt.add(adresse_plzort);
            } else {
                contactAddressPlzOrt.add("");
            }
            if (telefon != null && !telefon.equals("")) {
                contactTelephone.add(telefon);
            } else {
                contactTelephone.add("");
            }
            if (fax != null && !fax.equals("")) {
                contactFax.add(fax);
            } else {
                contactFax.add("");
            }
            if (email != null && !email.equals("")) {
                contactEmail.add(email);
            } else {
                contactEmail.add("");
            }
            if (website != null && !website.equals("")) {
                contactWebsite.add(website);
            } else {
                contactWebsite.add("");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        errorHappened = true;
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        errorHappened = true;
    }
```

I think this is all working... But I think here is my error somewhere... This is the `getChildView()` method of my Adapter which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);
        }

        TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);

        switch (childPosition) {
            case 0:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactAddressStreet.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 1:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactAddressPlzOrt.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 2:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactTelephone.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 3:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactFax.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 4:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactEmail.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 5:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactWebsite.get(childPosition));
                break;
            case 6:
                tvPlayerName
                        .setText(MainActivity.contactOpening.get(childPosition));
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

The problem is, that it always takes the same entries for all children in all group. It takes the first entry (Berlin) in all children as first, the second entry of the second one (East Highway 1) in all children as second etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way you built the data for the `ExpandableListView` and in the way you tried to show it in the `getChildView()` method.

You parse that `JSON` data in lists of equal size where each position in the lists is a piece of the data for one `JSON` object. In the `getChildView` method you use the `childPosition` to get the data for that child from the right list. But using the `childPosition` is wrong as you'll see the current behaviour.

Group 1(Berlin)

- childPosition == 0 (use the first position from `contactAddressStreet` to get the data(`"Hauptstrasse 1"`))
- childPosition == 1 (use the second position from `contactAddressPlzOrt` to get the data(`"London"`)))

Group 2(London)

- childPosition == 0 (use the first position from `contactAddressStreet` to get the data(`"Hauptstrasse 1"`))
- childPosition == 1 (use the second position from `contactAddressPlzOrt` to get the data(`"London"`)))

As you see, you don't take in consideration the group for which this child is requested and you get the same data no matter what.

To make it work, use the `childPosition` to use the correct list of data and the `groupPosition` to get the actual value from the lists:

```
// ...
case 0: // child 0
     tvPlayerName.setText(MainActivity.contactAddressStreet.get(groupPosition));
     break;
// ...
```

Another way would be to parse the `JSON` objects in a data structure more suitable for an `ExpandableListView`.